# Bell's Theorem: Help with understanding final bit of wikipedia proof (tensor products)

Tags: quantum-spin, tensor-calculus, bells-inequality

I'm trying to understand [this derivation of Bell's Theorem on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell's_theorem#Bell_inequalities_are_violated_by_quantum_mechanical_predictions).

I've never encountered tensor products before, but from my reading I gather that the first bit of the tensor product acts on the first particle, and the second bit acts on the second particle. I tried using the Pauli matrices to work through the problem explicitly but I can't seem to get the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ result. This is what I did:

$$\left|+x\right\rangle = \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
1
\end{matrix} \right),\ \left|-x\right\rangle = \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right)$$

\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \left|+x\right\rangle \otimes\left|-x\right\rangle -\left|-x\right\rangle \otimes\left|+x\right\rangle \right)
\\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right) - \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
1
\end{matrix} \right) \right)
\\ & = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right) + \left( \begin{matrix}-1\\
1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}-1\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right) \right)
\end{align}

The expected value of operators $AB$ is

$$\langle AB\rangle = \langle \psi |AB| \psi\rangle$$

In Wikipedia's notation I'm considering the case $(a,b)$, with operators $A=A(a)=S_z\otimes I$ and $B=B(b)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}I \otimes (S_X+S_Z)$. The operator B isthen

$$B = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}I \otimes (S_Z + S_X) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right)\otimes \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{matrix} \right) \right)$$

so when operated on $\psi$ I get
$$B|\psi \rangle = -\frac{1}{2}\left[\left( \begin{matrix}1\\
1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}0\\
2
\end{matrix} \right) + \left( \begin{matrix}-1\\
1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}-2\\
0
\end{matrix} \right)\right]$$

As for $A$,

$$A = S_Z \otimes I = \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right)$$

so

$$AB|\psi \rangle = -\frac{1}{2}\left[ \left( \begin{matrix}1\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}0\\
2
\end{matrix} \right) +\left( \begin{matrix}-1\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix}-2\\
0
\end{matrix} \right)\right].$$

Then to do the inner product I need to make the bra $\langle \psi|$ by flipping everything inside into row vectors:

$$\langle \psi| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[ (1\ \ \ 1)\ \otimes\ (1\ \ -1)\ + (-1\ \ \  1)\ \otimes\ (-1\ \  -1) \right]$$

Finally, I get
$$\langle \psi | AB | \psi \rangle = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[ 0 \otimes -2 + 0 \otimes 2 \right] = ?$$

At this point I don't know where I've gone wrong. I don't know what the value in the square brackets is (do they just multiply like normal numbers now?), but I don't see any way for it to be $-2,$ which is what it needs to be in order to cancel properly and make the thing equal $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. Am I not doing the inner product properly here? Have I completely misunderstood how tensors work?

Comment: LaTeX tip: `\begin{pmatrix}` is way easier than lugging around a bunch of `\left(` and `\right)`s.

Comment: A small unimportant  mistake : you forgot a $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ prefactor in front of your definition of $|±x\rangle$

Answer (score 2):

You are unduly dropping some terms when you take the inner product between $⟨\psi|$ and $AB|\psi⟩$. You need to multiply everything against everything, because the inner product distributes over the sums. Schematically, you need to do
\begin{align}
\bigg(⟨a|\otimes⟨b|+⟨c|\otimes⟨d|\bigg) & · \bigg(|e⟩\otimes |f⟩+|g⟩\otimes|h⟩\bigg)
\\ &=
⟨a|\otimes⟨b|·|e⟩\otimes |f⟩+⟨c|\otimes⟨d|·|g⟩\otimes|h⟩
\\ & \quad +⟨a|\otimes⟨b|·|g⟩\otimes|h⟩+⟨c|\otimes⟨d|·|e⟩\otimes |f⟩
\\ &=
⟨a|e⟩⟨b|f⟩+⟨c|g⟩⟨d|h⟩
\\ & \quad +⟨a|g⟩⟨b|h⟩+⟨c|e⟩⟨d|f⟩
.
\end{align}
You've done the $⟨a|e⟩⟨b|f⟩$ and $⟨c|g⟩⟨d|h⟩$ terms, but you're missing the $⟨a|g⟩⟨b|h⟩$ and $⟨c|e⟩⟨d|f⟩$ ones.

In your example, your calculation of the two sides of the inner product,
$$AB|\psi \rangle = -\frac{1}{2}\left[
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix} 
\otimes \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}  
+\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}
\otimes \begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\end{pmatrix}
\right]$$
and
$$\langle \psi| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix} 
\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\end{pmatrix} 
\otimes \begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\end{pmatrix}
\right]$$
is correct in its broad strokes. However, you overdid the signs when absorbing the singlet's substraction into both terms of the tensor product (instead of just one), and you missed a beat in the normalization of your basis states, which should read
$$
\left|+x\right\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}
,\ 
\left|-x\right\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}.$$
This changes your two inner-product factors to
$$AB|\psi \rangle = -\frac{1}{4}\left[
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix} 
\otimes \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}  
+\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\otimes \begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\end{pmatrix}
\right]$$
and
$$\langle \psi| = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \left[
 \begin{pmatrix} 1&1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1& 1\end{pmatrix}
\right],$$
respectively, and introduces a global factor of $1/4$ with respect to your current result.

For the first inner product (i.e. the $⟨a|e⟩⟨b|f⟩$ term), then, you get
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}
·
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix} 
& = 
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix} ·\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix} \times
\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}·\otimes \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix} 
\\ & = 
0\times(-2)
\\ & = 
0.
\end{align}
Here the two single-particle inner products $⟨a|e⟩⟨b|f⟩$ just multiply as complex numbers - they *are* just complex numbers. Zero times whatever is always zero.

The other term in your calculation is also zero:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}
·
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\end{pmatrix} 
& = 
\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\end{pmatrix} ·\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} \times
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}·\otimes \begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\end{pmatrix} 
\\ & = 
0\times (-2)
\\ & = 
0.
\end{align}
However, there are also two other terms that contribute:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}
·
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\end{pmatrix} 
& = 
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix} ·\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} \times
\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}·\otimes \begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\end{pmatrix} 
\\ & = 
2 \times (-2)
\\ & = 
-4,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}
·
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix} 
& = 
\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\end{pmatrix} ·\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix} \times
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}·\otimes \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix} 
\\ & = 
(-2) \times 2
\\ & = 
-4.
\end{align}

Putting all of this together, then, we get
$$
⟨\psi|AB|\psi⟩
=\frac{-1}{8\sqrt{2}}(-4-4)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},
$$
as it needs to be.

---

Oh, and one final hint: these calculations are *way* easier if you do them on the canonical basis,
$$
\left|+x'\right\rangle =\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}
,\ 
\left|-x'\right\rangle =\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
using the more standard expression for the spin singlet state,
$$
|\psi' \rangle = 
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}  
-\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
It will be a good exercise in the handling of tensor products to show that this $|\psi'⟩$ coincides with the $|\psi⟩$ defined above.

Comment: Why don't scalars (like the -1 in the singlet) distribute over both terms of the tensor product?

Comment: (adding another comment because I can't edit) Also shouldn't it be $|+z'\rangle$ and $|-z'\rangle$ at the end, since those are the eigenvectors of the $S_Z$ operator?